# Exact meaning of actual times in PostgreSQL explain analyze

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, explain

There are many places that talk about this question but none fully explain it - all leave it ambiguous. Examples:

- [PostgreSQL's own documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE)
- [pgMustard's page on the topic](https://www.pgmustard.com/blog/calculating-per-operation-times-in-postgres-explain-analyze)

From what I've been able to gather, the following factors are at play:

1. The two times T0 and T1 included in the `(actual time=<T0>..<T1> rows=<R> loops=<L>)` output.
2. Total number of threads: one "leader" + any number of concurrent (parallel) "workers". If there are two workers that means 1+2=3 threads.
3. Number of "loops" (L in the above example, "executions", iterations).

I'll include the actual [documentation example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT *
FROM tenk1 t1, tenk2 t2
WHERE t1.unique1 < 10 AND t1.unique2 = t2.unique2;

                                                           QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------​--------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=4.65..118.62 rows=10 width=488) (actual time=0.128..0.377 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tenk1 t1  (cost=4.36..39.47 rows=10 width=244) (actual time=0.057..0.121 rows=10 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (unique1 < 10)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tenk1_unique1  (cost=0.00..4.36 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=10 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (unique1 < 10)
   ->  Index Scan using tenk2_unique2 on tenk2 t2  (cost=0.29..7.91 rows=1 width=244) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=1 loops=10)
         Index Cond: (unique2 = t1.unique2)
 Planning time: 0.181 ms
 Execution time: 0.501 ms
```

and the official explanation:

> Note that the “actual time” values are in milliseconds of real time, ... *<unrelated text about "cost" removed for brevity>*.
>
> In some query plans, it is possible for a subplan node to be executed more than once. For example, the inner index scan will be executed once per outer row in the above nested-loop plan. In such cases, the loops value reports the total number of executions of the node, and the actual time and rows values shown are averages per-execution. This is done to make the numbers comparable with the way that the cost estimates are shown. Multiply by the loops value to get the total time actually spent in the node. In the above example, we spent a total of 0.220 milliseconds executing the index scans on tenk2.

When there is only one thread and loops=1, things appear **almost** clear:

1. **T0** is effectively the clock start time of the "node".
2. **T1** is effectively the clock completion time of the "node".

... and a nice execution time diagram could be made. However, this does not add up to the example given. *T1* of the root node in the above example is 0.377ms yet indicated execution time at the end is 0.501ms, which is 0.124ms longer. That is less than the planning time (0.181ms) so it can't be included there. It is also less than T0=0.128ms, though T0+T1 do come close to 0.505ms, mere 0.004ms longer. This could be explained by some sort of time accounting errors but it would imply that *T1* is not the clock "completion time" but the "raw execution" time and that the completion time is T0+T1... and that fails to match the observed reality. I have a case were T1 does match the end time and T0 is very little less than T1, would add up to almost double the total time spent ... for queries that run much longer (and would not be prone to accounting errors).  In other words, in all observed cases I saw, T1 is inclusive of T0 and T1 is always greater than T0.

Then we come to "loops" (still assuming a single thread, for now). In the example the **Index Scan** on **tenk2** states:

```
(actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=1 loops=10)
```

... and documentation states that this is taking T1*L = 0.022ms/loop * 10 loops=0.220ms total. That seems to "adjust" the definition of T1 to one of the following:

- **T1** is the total time taken by one average execution.

But what do loops/executions mean for T0? Does T1 continue to be inclusive of T0? I can see the following possibilities:

1. **T0 is the group clock time before loops begin.** The raw execution time is T1 * L - T0 = 0.022ms/loop * 10loops - 0.021ms = 0.220ms - 0.021ms = 0.199ms.
2. **T0 is not the group clock start time but the iteration initialization time.** The raw execution time is (T1 - T0) * L = (0.022ms/loop - 0.021ms/loop) * 10loops = 0.001ms/loop * 10loops = 0.010ms.
3. **I was wrong and T1 no longer includes T0 and T0 is per loop.** Raw execution times is simple T1*L now (0.220ms) and that occurs in addition to T0*L=0.210ms for a combined total of (T0+T1)*L=0.430ms. This can't be because the root node completed earlier, at 0.430ms... or maybe not ... as execution time took 0.501ms?
4. **As above but T0 is not per loop.**. Total time is T0+(T1*L)=0.021ms+0.220ms=0.241ms. That's longer than the root node's T0... but perhaps these can overlap even when not concurrent by means of interleaving - streaming data processing within a single thread.

Then we come to threads (extra workers). They make things even more "interesting" as whatever we do with multiplying by loops (may) now need(s) to be divided by the number of threads, but depending on the exact meanings of T0 and T1 this is different. When the number of threads = number of loops things seem to cancel out but due to previous ambiguity I'm done with forensic analysis and came here...

Can someone, please, explain what's going on here? What **exactly** are T0 and T1 and how are they affected by loops and threads?

What is T0 here? I can see two possibilities:

1. **The start time of the first execution**, should not be multiplied by L=10, so the execution time is T1 * L - T0 = 0.022ms/loop * 10loops - 0.021ms = 0.220ms - 0.021ms = 0.199ms.
2. **The wait/delay time within each execution** (should be multiplied by L=10), so the execution time is (T1 - T0) * L = (0.022ms/loop - 0.021ms/loop) * 10loops = 0.001ms/loop * 10loops = 0.010ms.

Comment: I'm happy to answer a single question, but Stackoverflow isn't the forum for a comprehensive tutorial on what the numbers in `EXPLAIN` mean.

Comment: You might want to take a look at here [depesz Explain Help](https://explain.depesz.com/help).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: This is a single question. What are T0 and T1? I just documented the ambiguity well so that I don't get superficial answers to what I already know.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Thanks! I'm aware of that and some other similar tools... but I am struggling to understand the meaning of what comes from PostgreSQL itself. These tools may show some of the information but I can't find the actual descriptions of values.

Comment: Did you actually read the Help, it goes into what the various parts mean.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Yes, in fact, I have. It does go to some level of detail but not more than I've already found elsewhere. It mainly talks of columns and colours. The inclusive and exclusive times indicated all appear based on what I refer to as T1 in my question, which is somewhat less problematic than T0, for which there is no information.

Answer (score 0):

This is the meaning of the two times reported by `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` as `actual time`:

- the first number is the time from the beginning of the statement execution until this execution plan node returned the first result row
- the second number is the time from the beginning of the statement execution until the execution plan node was done

All times are in milliseconds.

If `loops` of an execution plan step is greater than one, there can be two cases

1. The `loops` indicate repeated execution in a single thread, like on the inner side of a nested loop join. In that case, you have to multiply the second number with the `loops` value to get the total time spent executing this execution plan step.
2. The `loops` indicate parallel execution in parallel worker processes (look at the `Gather` node to find the actual number of workers). In that case, these processes execute in parallel, so you don't have to multiply and the second number is the average time it took to complete that step.

It is easy to tell how many parallel workers there are from the `Workers Launched` of the `Gather` node that is higher up in the execution plan tree. The two cases above can also occur in combination if several parallel workers each execute a step several times.

Comment: OK - thank you for that but that explanation only matches the official documentation for loops=1. The "node" is done when all the loops are done and they suggest that the second number (at least) needs to be multiplied by the number of loops to get the total time. As they say "... the actual time and rows values shown are averages per-execution. ... Multiply by the loops value to get the total time actually spent in the node."

Comment: Yes, it is an average if you are using parallel query. Multiplying only makes sense if you want to know how much CPU time was spent. If you are interested in the execution time, the displayed values are the useful ones, because the parallel workers execute in parallel.

Comment: That appears to match my observations but not the official statement where the time needs to be multiplied by the number of loops even when not parallel.

Comment: I hope my extended answer clarifies that.

Comment: I very much appreciate your effort but docs elsewhere state that T1 ("the second number") is always to be multiplied by loops (and divided by total threads: workers + one extra/lead). T0 ("the first number") remains unclear w.r.t. loops and workers.

Comment: What you quoted above only says that you need to multiply if you want to know the total time spent in that node. But you are not interested in the total processing time (which happens on several cores in parallel), but in the response time. You can spend 5 seconds of CPU time in one second.

Comment: The actual example they provided has no parallel workers, it is single-threaded and, yet, they multiplied it by loops.

Comment: Exactly, and that's what my answer says too: if it is *not* parallel query, all the loop executions happen in a single thread, one after the other, and you have to multiply to get the actual execution time.

Comment: But that is not a complete answer - I need clarification on the meaning when parallelism is in effect.